# Why is Google giving me Page with Redirect error when trying to index the page?

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, wordpress

I'm trying to index a landing page through the Google Search Console. The result I get is error *Page with redirect: The URL is a redirect, and therefore was not added to the index.* The error explanation which Google gives is:

> If you link to an old version of a URL that redirects to a new one,
>   Google will still detect that URL and include it in the Coverage
>   Report. Consider updating any link using the old version of the URL so
>   search engines aren’t forced to go through a redirect to discover your
>   content.

I have not created any redirects for the page and when I used redirect-checker.org I got: *CONGRATULATION. Everything seems to be fine.*  There is no old version of the URL.

The page was created with WordPress.

Can you throw any light on this?

Answer (score 1):

Note that Googlebot sees the following entries differently:

1. `http://example.com`
2. `https://example.com`
3. `http://www.example.com`
4. `https://www.example.com`

If you are trying to list for example **1.**, but your site uses by default `https` like in **2.** then you got a redirect when you open **1.**

*Can you provide your website URL to give you a better answer?*